# SQL Query with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE does not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with profiles. If there is a profile for user #:userId, I want to UPDATE it. If there is no profile for that user, I want to INSERT it. I tried this SQL query, but it did not work:

```
    INSERT INTO profiles 
    SET name = :name, 
        website = :website, 
        bio = :bio 
    WHERE user = :userId 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        name = :name, 
        website = :website, 
        bio = :bio
```

'user' is primary key

**EDIT:** I found a mistake in my SQL, when it looks like this, it works just fine:

```
    INSERT INTO profiles 
    SET user = :userId,  -- <-- mistake was here
        name = :name, 
        website = :website, 
        bio = :bio 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        name = :name, 
        website = :website, 
        bio = :bio
```

**Thanks, everyone!**

Comment: You said **user** is the primary key, but that's not in your query.

Answer (score 2):

Your INSERT syntax is incorrect (it looks like a modified UPDATE statement). Try something like:

```
INSERT INTO profiles (name, website, bio)
       VALUES (:name, :website, :bio)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE website = :website, bio = :bio;
```

See the [documentation for INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for further information and examples.

Comment: INSERT INTO ... SET syntax is actually correct, and it works ( http://milov.nl/2836 ). But when I use this syntax with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE it becomes incorrect. It it a MySQL's "feature"?

Comment: INSERT INTO ... SET is not standard SQL and must be a Mysql extension.